# Google Cloud SDK App-Engine project priority

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, jenkins, google-cloud-sdk

To deploy my app I use this in **bash**:

```
mvn appengine:deploy -Dproject=projectname1
```

This is my **pom.xml**:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <project>projectname2</project>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

At the moment, my app is deployed in projectname2 while I want it to ignore pom's project configuration and **give priority on the sh** one.

I red the Cloud SDK documentation but I didn't notice how to do.

I need this to choose where Jenkins will deploy the app on, regardless the pom's plugin setting.

Comment: Can't you just remove the `<configuration>` altogether and only rely on the `-Dproject` parameter?

Comment: Obviously I can, but who pushes on git won't should be able to modify the pom's project configuration in order to push in another one.